# Is it possible to use Java based migration with Flyway and Jenkins

Tags: java, database, jenkins, flyway

I want to launch migrations using the flyway Jenkins plugin. There are SQL and java based migrations. But I don't know is it possible to run these migrations in such a way?

I tried to execute flyway in such a way

```
flyway -url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/?db=xxx&user=xxx&password=xxx" -locations="classpath:db.migration"  migrate
```

in the directory where the project located is and got such an error:
ERROR: Unable to resolve location classpath:db.migration

Comment: Are you executing this command in a jenkins job?

Comment: I think, location should be some path not package name, something like `target/classes/db/migrations` but I have never used the plugin so you can try this if it works for you.

Comment: @marcin.programuje no, I do that locally

Comment: It should not be the classpath, you have to select the relative/absolute path to migration scripts directory.

Comment: @marcin.programuje thanks for your answer. I want to add that I execute it in my local machine for test purposes. Of course,  as a result, I want to add this to Jenkin job. So it means that in Jenkins I don't need to use the "directory" path instead of classpath?